# How to create a work item type, that is shown under related item, but not on backlog?

Tags: azure-devops, scrum

i need help creating a work item type, or a rule that can be used for work items, so they won't be displayed in backlogs, but they should be visible in boards and sprints.

I tried to create a new item work type under custom process and create a rule for it that won't put this new item in the backlog, but i can't see any action that would 'block' this particular item from going into the backlog.